# System.ArgumentException: "No recognizer of the required ID found. Arg_ParamName_Name"

Tags: c#, распознавание-речи

Хотел сделать приложение для перевода. Накидал небольшой код по гайдам. Но выбрасывается исключение. С чем это может быть связано? Языковой [пакет](https://clck.ru/34hxJc) скачал. В переменной `installedRecognizedrs`  отображаются только en-US и en-UK. Вот код.

```
var installedRecognizedrs = SpeechRecognitionEngine.InstalledRecognizers();

CultureInfo cultureInfo = new CultureInfo("ru-RU");

SpeechRecognitionEngine recognitionEngine = new SpeechRecognitionEngine(cultureInfo);//Error System.ArgumentException: "No recognizer of the required ID found. Arg_ParamName_Name"
recognitionEngine.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();

recognitionEngine.SpeechRecognized += new EventHandler<SpeechRecognizedEventArgs>(recognitionEngine_Recognize);

Choices numbers = new Choices();
numbers.Add(new string[] { "Один", "Два", "Три"});

GrammarBuilder grammarBuilder = new GrammarBuilder();
grammarBuilder.Append(numbers);

Grammar grammar = new Grammar(grammarBuilder);
recognitionEngine.LoadGrammar(grammar);

recognitionEngine.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Single);
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй скачать пакет с именем **MSSpeech_SR_ru-RU_TELE.msi**, у меня тоже была такая проблема и я скачивал файл **MSSpeech_TTS_ru-RU_Elena.msi** - но это совершенно не то

Comment: Переустановил. Безрезультатно.